# IIS 8.5 JSON data sending as html when over 196B

Tags: json, ajax, iis-8

I have a note taking application (.net core) running on Windows server 2012, IIS 8.5.  I send an Ajax get to update text fields in the database, and when debugging on my local machine everything works.  While using the deployed application I noticed that if I have a somewhat long text description (example below, the database field is `nvarchar(max)`) I see a 404 in the console (firefox) and the update function silently fails.  I have narrowed down the length that succeeds, and adding a single character then fails (I'll post the text at the bottom).  My response headers in the networking panel are interesting however:

The text below in a code block is what I can enter and successfully save back to the database.  Adding a single character (like a space after the last "in") then results in the 404.  The successful size shows json at 196B transferred.  The failure (with just a single character more) shows html at 1.42KB transferred.  So it seems like my ajax call is not serializing the data correctly when the data is over 196B.

Image snip of network activity:

[image]

Does this indicate that the serialization is failing? And this is all happening on the client side, (json serialization) rather than server?  This only happens on the deployment server, when I run through debugger I can successfully add many times the text below.

Here is my jquery function to update the database:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMeetingItem", "Meetings")',
    data: { "id": id, "DateOpen": DateOpen, "DateClosed": DateClosed, "Responsibility": Responsibility, "descID": d_ID, "Description": Description },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.result == true) {
         //do stuff here
        }
        else { alert("There is some error updating the Meeting Item."); }
    }
})
```

and the text length that works, with no ability to add another character (not sure this is useful, but is interesting perhaps):

```
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in  the production server application.  On the development side I don't see any issues.
This is just a bunch of sample text to attempt to reproduce the problem I see in
```

I am now using a POST rather than get, and after adding `[FromBody]` before the post model object (created to mirror the properties I was sending in the GET request) in my controller:

```
public JsonResult UpdateMeetingItem([FromBody]MeetingPostModel m) 
{ ... update database and other stuff here . . . }
```

Which works as expected.  So now going back and converting all of my `GET` to `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below code in web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration> 
       <system.web.extensions>
           <scripting>
               <webServices>
                   <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000" />
               </webServices>
           </scripting>
       </system.web.extensions>
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10485760" />
      </system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10737418240" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483644" />
    </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: I have since changed this to use a POST rather than GET, as after a lot more reading I found some references to the size of GETs being limited (without quantifying) as well as recommendations to more correctly use GET/POST/PUT/DELETE as best practice.  I'm thinking that technically I should use PUT, but have not looked into that yet.